# git status shows "\n\n" as an untracked file

Tags: git

```
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   "\n\n"
#   .gitignore
#   public_html/_tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/0c50971a0f1f60d2408f9bd7eed5a979.gz
```

It doesn't break anything but that "\n\n" looks strange.

I tried `git rm` but it wouldn't work.

Any idea what is causing this and how to get rid of it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you managed to make a file with a name that's just two newlines. You should double-check that it's empty first

```
cat $'\n\n'
```

Then you can delete it with

```
rm $'\n\n'
```

`git rm` will only remove files that are part of the repository, so it won't work with untracked files.

Comment: Ok morning coffe wasn't strong enough to remember `git rm` vs `rm` LMAO. I didn't know the `$` prefix trick and what `cat` does tho but thanks it worked. :)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how it got there but you can probably delete it by doing:

```
rm '\n\n'
```